# What is the purpose of retrieveByToken method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am implementing custom User Provider in `Laravel` which implemens `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` interface.
I am wondering who is using following methods and what is the purpose of the following methods:

- `public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)`
- `public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)`
- `public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)`

at the moment I have those 3 methods empty and App running fine.

For example method description for `public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)` is following: **Retrieve a user by their unique identifier and "remember me" token.**
For me this is confusing. Method name implicitly tells me that method should find a user using token and description tellms that method should find a user by id and token is for some other purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this thread comes up when searching google for `retrieveByToken`, I'll add a [current link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#the-user-provider-contract) to the docs that explains what this method is supposed to do. And provide it here:

`retrieveByToken`

> The retrieveByToken function retrieves a user by their unique $identifier and "remember me" $token, typically stored in a database column like remember_token. As with the previous method, the Authenticatable implementation with a matching token value should be returned by this method.

*You don't need to implement this method if you aren't using remember me functionality.*

To further answer the question the other methods are more obvious in their role:

`updateRememberToken`

> The updateRememberToken method updates the $user instance's remember_token with the new $token. A fresh token is assigned to users on a successful "remember me" authentication attempt or when the user is logging out.

*Again, You don't need to implement this method if you aren't using remember me functionality.*

`validateCredentials`

> The validateCredentials method should compare the given $user with the $credentials to authenticate the user. For example, this method will typically use the Hash::check method to compare the value of $user->getAuthPassword() to the value of $credentials['password']. This method should return true or false indicating whether the password is valid.

*You should be implementing this, not sure how else you are verify passwords?*